# How to tell what AWS credentials Spark is using to read S3 files?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, oozie

I am running an Oozie job that previously was running fine. And now I have a permission denied error when accessing S3 files. I am just trying to figure out which credentials it is using and where to fix them.

As far as I can tell credentials seems to come from several locations and not sure the order of precedence (e.g. ~/.aws/credentials, environment variables, hadoop configuration, IAM role, etc).

Is there a way to tell which is the active credentials being used? Is it possible to print the active AWS account key id in the spark logging?

Comment: Do you use EMR or install your own spark on EC2 ? Do you use Oozie to trigger spark job ?

Comment: It is a Cloudera cluster. Yes, Oozie triggered the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. AWS login details don't really get logged for security reasons.
2. Spark submit will pick up the AWS_ env vars from your desktop and set the fs.s3a values, overriding any in there.

In the s3a connector, the order is

1. secrets in the URI (bad, avoid, removed from recent releases)
2. fs.s3a properties
3. env vars
4. IAM credentials supplied to an EC2 VM

you can [configure the list of authentication providers](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Authenticating_with_S3) to change the order, remove them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because you running Cloudera cluster, you may have read this document [Make a modified copy of the configuration files](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/cm_s3_clients.html)

It is better to add the following to the core-site.xml file within the  element:

```xml
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
    <value>Amazon S3 Access Key</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
    <value>Amazon S3 Secret Key</value>
</property>
```